# Showing that normal line passes through a point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I need to show that a line passes through a point. How should I go about doing this? The question is:

> Let $L$ be the normal line at $(1,1,1)$ to the level surface of $f(x,y,z) = x^2 - z$ that passes through $(1,1,1)$. Show that $L$ passes through the point $(3,1,0)$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I tried taking the gradient, where the gradient is (2,0,-1). So L would be 2(x-1)-(z-1) = 0. Is this right? If it is, how do I show that it passes through the point?

Edit 2: How do I show that it passes through (3,1,0)? (1+2(3),1,1-(0))?

Edit 3: So you're saying that t_0 = 1? I'm confused as to how does this show that L passes through the point.

Edit 4: Can you please show an example where the point is NOT in L? Thanks!

Edit 5: So conflicting values of t? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that $\nabla f(1,1,1)$ is a normal vector to the surface at said point. Hence, the normal line is: $$L: \quad {\bf X}(t) = (1,1,1) + t \nabla f (1,1,1), \quad t \in \Bbb R.$$

To show the claim, you must find $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ such that ${\bf X}(t_0) = (3,1,0)$. Ok?

Comment: If it's okay with you, could you please provide the full solution to this question? I have a midterm about this in a few hours and I would really appreciate it if you could show me how to do it step by step. Thanks!

Comment: the gradient is (2,0,-1) right? So L would be 2(x-1)-(z-1) = 0. Is this right?

Comment: I think that the best way to learn is to do it yourself. But I can keep checking your work (add it as an edit to the question)

Comment: The gradient is correct. The way you wrote it, $2(x-1)-(z-1) = 0$ is the equation of a plane, not of a line. To find a line, you need a point and a vector, so: $${\bf X}(t) = (1,1,1)+t(2,0,-1) = (1+2t,1,1-t).$$

Comment: How do I show that it passes through (3,1,0)? (1+2(3),1,1-(0))?

Comment: No. The line depends on a single parameter $t$, not on a point. You're thinking backwards: we want to find $t_0$ such that: $$(1+2t_0,1,1-t_0) = (3,1,0).$$
Looking at each coordinate, we get three relations. One of them is useless, $1=1$. Look at the other two. On one of them, you'll find a suitable value for $t_0$. The same $t_0$ has to work in the other expression, otherwise the point won't be in the line.

Comment: So you're saying that t_0 = 1? I'm confused as to how does this show that L passes through the point.

Comment: Yes, $t_0 = 1$, and this shows the result. I think you're confused with the definition of belonging in the line. We have: $$L = \{(1+2t,1,1-t)\in \Bbb R^3 \mid t \in \Bbb R\}.$$
If a point $(x,y,z)$ is in $L$, then must exist $t \in \Bbb R$ such that $(x,y,z) = (1+2t,1,1-t)$.

Comment: Can you please show an example where the point is NOT in L? Thanks!

Comment: Take the same line, and the point $(3,2,1)$, for example. Is there a value of $t$ such that $(3,2,1) = (1+2t,1,1-t)$?

Comment: So conflicting values of t? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Another point not in the line is, say, $(3,1,-1)$. Everything must work smoothly. The example before is clear because $1 \neq 2$, but there isn't conflicting values for $t$. In this one, we'll get conflicting values for $t$ indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If the line passes through the two given points, its direction vector is $(3,1,0)-(1,1,1)=(2,0,-1)$, indeed parallel to the gradient.